# Sql Query Taking too much time with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table containing 5m records by today. By the time this data will increase to 1 or 2 billion records. My task to generate an summary report from this data, for this I am  using below query.

```
SELECT creation_date
    ,caller_circle
    ,count(id)
FROM call_reporting
WHERE enterprise_id = 206
GROUP BY DATE (creation_date)
    ,caller_circle limit 10;
```

Table structure looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `call_reporting` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SESSION_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CALLER_NUMBER` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DIALED_NUMBER` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CALL_START_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CALL_END_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `OUT_CALL_START_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `OUT_CALL_END_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `HUNTING_START_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `IN_CALL_DURATION` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OUT_CALL_DURATION` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HUNTING_DURATION` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADV_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTERPRISE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AGENT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HUNT_TRY` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CALL_STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URL_CALLING_STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REMARKS` text,
  `REF_NO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_CALL_RESULT` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATION_DATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `AGENT_DIAL_OUT_NUMBER` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA_SYNC` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CALLER_CIRCLE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS_CODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPERATOR_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OBD_RESULT_STATUS` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_SENT` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SDR_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KEY_PRESS` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTERPRISE_USER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMAIGN_NAME` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DND_NO` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  KEY `ENTERPRISE_ID` (`ENTERPRISE_ID`),
  KEY `SDR_ID` (`SDR_ID`),
  KEY `CALLER_NUMBER` (`CALLER_NUMBER`),
  KEY `CREATION_DATE` (`CREATION_DATE`),
  KEY `DIALED_NUMBER` (`DIALED_NUMBER`),
  KEY `CALLER_CIRCLE` (`CALLER_CIRCLE`),
  KEY `CAMAIGN_NAME` (`CAMAIGN_NAME`),
  KEY `ADV_ID` (`ADV_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2612658 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (MONTH(CREATION_DATE))
PARTITIONS 12 */ |
```

This table contain partition also. but when i run the given query it takes

```
10 rows in set (15.11 sec)
```

When i have seen the query profile it gives the following stat.

```
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                         | Duration  |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| starting                       |  0.000052 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   |  0.000017 |
| checking query cache for query |  0.000106 |
| checking permissions           |  0.000023 |
| Opening tables                 |  0.000051 |
| System lock                    |  0.000035 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   |  0.000015 |
| init                           |  0.000085 |
| optimizing                     |  0.000036 |
| statistics                     |  0.003924 |
| preparing                      |  0.000075 |
| Creating tmp table             |  0.000077 |
| executing                      |  0.000014 |
| Copying to tmp table           | 16.945653 |
| Sorting result                 |  0.000879 |
| Sending data                   |  0.001254 |
| end                            |  0.000012 |
| removing tmp table             |  0.000017 |
| end                            |  0.000010 |
| query end                      |  0.000013 |
| closing tables                 |  0.000019 |
| freeing items                  |  0.000030 |
| logging slow query             |  0.000008 |
| logging slow query             |  0.000008 |
| cleaning up                    |  0.000007 |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
25 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

It is taking two much to copy data into temp table; Is there any way to reduce this execution time. In my case temp table size is

```
 tmp_table_size                         | 16777216 |
```

I was also thinking to load data into RAM. But do not the pros and cons of it. Because in my case data size will grow expansion. Please give a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have on this table?

Comment: Index Type BTree, Column - ID, Enterprise_Id, Sdr_id, caller_number, Dialed_number, cAller_circle, Campaing_Name, Av_id

Comment: Cardinality is , 2602135, 24, 650533, 2602135,, 236557, 24,24, 24 as per above column order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a covering index on

( enterprise_id, creation_date, caller_circle )

This way, the WHERE clause is optimized by the ID, and the GROUP BY can be used from the index too.

Also, change from "count(ID)" to just "count(*)" so the engine does not have to go to the page to get the ID, it just knows a record qualified from the covering index.

I would then suggest creating a secondary table that holds the simple aggregate roll-ups for the given enterprise, date and caller circle.  That is... if the raw data won't change historically (such as back-filling call data).  It happened, it's done, the totals are what they are for the historical date.  Then, if anything needs to be re-calibrated, you could rebuild on a gradual basis, such as for a month/year so you are not plowing through a billion records in the future.

Comment: should i delete the partition or both index or partition will improve the performance

Comment: @naveen, Don't know enough about partitioning context of your datato help with this respect.  By partitioning by month, and then what does that do for years...  What are your queries going to be primarily based on-- Date Ranges, enterprises, caller circles?  Not enough to really offer better answer on that.

Comment: Table will contain data only for last 2 month not more than that, table is already partitioned by month hash key.